# Immanuel / Emmanuel the angel

Tags: tanach, malach-angel

I recently ran across [a reference](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=kGXelGEMdWgC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=the%20angel%20in%20the%20fiery%20furnace%20who%20appeared%20beside%20Sidras,%20Misac,%20and%20Abednego&source=bl&ots=fA0ldLDhV6&sig=ACfU3U0yBQH5BzLSuaJUZawRqYEii5Jmgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzq_6w88vzAhW4QkEAHViJCJgQ6AF6BAgnEAM#v=onepage&q=emmanuel&f=false) to the angel named "Immanuel" or "Emmanuel" ... it reads:
Emmanuel ("God with us")-the angel in the
fiery furnace who appeared beside Sidras, Misac,
and Abednego. "..." In the cabala, Emmanuel is a
sefira of Malkuth (the Kingdom) in the Briatic
world. [Rf: Ambelain, [La Kabbale Pratiqtre](http://www.markfoster.net/rn/texts/practicalkabbalah-part1.pdf).]

Question 1. What is the Jewish / Torah source for the proposition that this angel is the one that saved Daniel's friends from the furnace?

Question 2: Is Ambelain, La Kabbale Pratique, an accepted Jewish source? if not, is there one that states this proposition stated here?

Thank you.

Note: the story of the three friends of Daniel in the furnace and them being saved by a fourth, who is an Angel is found in Daniel 3.
Link: https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16486/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-3.htm

Who is this angel?

Comment: The angel is not named in any of the commentaries or midrashim. It is just called one of the malachei hashareis, one of the administering angels.

Comment: Immanuel from the time of Isaiah is mentioned in [Shemot Rabbah 18:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shemot_Rabbah.18.5?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), a section which prior said that Gabriel was the angel that saved the three from the furnace. Other than that, I don't think there's any connection. He's not mentioned as an angel in Rabbi Dr. Reuven Margolies's book on angels mentioned in Chazalic literature.

Answer (score 3):

Ambelain is definitely not an accepted Jewish source. He doesn't seem to have been Jewish at all, and had Christian ordination, according to Wikipedia. As a general rule, no traditional Kabbalistic source would write a book of practical Kabbala for the masses, as actual practicing of Kabbala is understood to be extremely dangerous.

Comment: Jewish magic/mysticism became a topic of great interest for Christians during the Renaissance. A “trend” if you will. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Kabbalah).